# Is there a better way of creating this small guessing game in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, number-guessing-game

I have a guessing game in PowerShell trying to practice the while statement. I found this on the internet on someone's repo. I have a feeling it can be shortened but maybe I am wrong. This is pure for learning purposes.

```
  $ComputerNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 11
[int]$Tries = 3
'Please guess the number between 1 and 10 and now you have  ' + $Tries +  ' chances left'

[int]$YourGuess = Read-Host
$Tries = $Tries - 1

while($YourGuess -ne $ComputerNumber -and $Tries -gt 0)
{
    
    if($YourGuess -lt $ComputerNumber)
    {

        'Sorry that guess ' + $YourGuess +  ' is too low !!, Guess again!! you have ' + $Tries + ' chances left' 
 
    }

    
    elseif($YourGuess -gt $ComputerNumber)
    {

        'Sorry that guess ' + $YourGuess +  ' is too high !!, Guess again!! you have ' + $Tries + ' chances left' 
 
    }
    
    $YourGuess = Read-Host

    $Tries = $Tries - 1



}

""
if($YourGuess -eq $ComputerNumber)
{

    'YESSSS, you guessed it, the number is '+$ComputerNumber + ' and you have '+ $Tries +  ' chances left'

}

else
{

    'NOOOO NOT RIGHT IT WAS ' + $ComputerNumber + ' and you have '+ $Tries +  ' chances left'
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how this could be improved or maybe it is already good as it is.

regards

John

Comment: [1] move your `$Tries` decrement & your user input _into the loop_. that is where they belong. [*grin*] ///// [2] use a `switch` block instead of an `if/elseif` cascade. ///// [3] move your `right/wrong` into the loop. ///// [4] purely as a personal preference, i would use the `-f` string format operator instead of string concatenation. ///// [5] rearrange your indentation to make the loop ending much more obvious.

Comment: Did you write any portion of this yourself? If not, then the question is off-topic because you didn't write the code.

Comment: I guess the most surprising thing in your code is something new I learned about powershell: a string literal on its own line implicitly gets written to `Write-Output`. That is actually kind of nice.

Comment: You did not tell whether you are new to (imperative) programming, and/or PowerShell. Is the code presented yours to [publish under CC](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally move all conditions inside the loop and use a [`switch` statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2), this would improve the code readability (though highly opinionated).

Aside from that, the code you have is more than fine, the only thing that is missing is an input validation to make sure it is always within boundaries and it is a valid numeric digit. For that, one of many options, is a [function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2) (a recursive one, in this case). This function is using [`ValidateRange` Attribute Declaration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validaterange-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2), if the input is not within the declared boundaries it will throw an exception that is caught by the [`catch` block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2#catching-errors) which then calls the function again.

Notable mention, `-not $Tries` can also be seen as `$Tries -eq 0`, see [about Logical Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.2) and [about Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2) for more information.

```
$ComputerNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 11
$Tries = 3
$won = $false

function AskForNumber {
    try {
       [ValidateRange(1, 10)] [int] $YourGuess = Read-Host
       $YourGuess
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Invalid input, must be a number between 1 and 10! Try again"
        AskForNumber
    }
}

do {
    "Please guess the number between 1 and 10 and now you have $Tries chances left"
    $Tries--
    switch(AskForNumber) {
        { $_ -lt $ComputerNumber } {
            "Sorry that guess $_ is too low !!, Guess again!! you have $Tries chances left"
        }
        { $_ -gt $ComputerNumber } {
            "Sorry that guess $_ is too high !!, Guess again!! you have $Tries chances left"
        }
        { -not $Tries -and -not $won } {
            "NOOOO NOT RIGHT IT WAS $ComputerNumber and you have $Tries chances left"
            break
        }
        Default {
            "YESSSS, you guessed it, the number is $ComputerNumber and you have $Tries chances left"
            $won = $true
        }
    }
} until(-not $Tries -or $won)
```

Comment: while `-not $Tries` works ... i wonder how many folks will see it as what it is ... a boolean test. i suspect that most people would find `$Tries -eq 0` to be more obvious. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey well it might be true though it is also a matter of opinion. I added a link to logical and comparison operators.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is so helpful!!

Comment: happy to help @john hope you could learn something new :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - yep, it is a preference. i suspect that i deal with non-scripters so often that i just presume the code will be interpreted incorrectly if at all possible. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey oh yes, code being misinterpreted is always a possibility, but the docs are there for the ones who actually cares to actually reads them and want to learn something new (thanks btw for the feedback re `-not` vs `-eq 0`)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - you are most welcome! [*grin*]